# Javascript filter by test and boolean values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I feel like I should the answer to this but its escaping me right now.

Say I have an array of **Vendors** (this is dummy data):

```
[
  {
    "user_updated": null,
    "user_created": "128a84b5-275c-4f00-942e-e8ba6d85c60e",
    "date_created": "2021-03-13T23:41:09Z",
    "date_updated": null,
    "website": "www.example.com",
    "payment_information": "IBAN: THEIR1234IBAN567",
    "tax_id": null,
    "vat_id": "1234567890",
    "services": "Produzione video, animazioni",
    "name": "Video Productions Ltd.",
    "address": "Viale Lorenteggio, 20\nMilano 20142",
    "notes": "Competenze di alto livello",
    "id": 1,
    "inactive": false
  }
]
```

I want to filter by `name`, `services`, `website` which I was able to do using:

```
data() {
  return {
    filter: ''
  }
},
computed: {
  filteredVendors() {
    return this.vendors.filter(({name, notes, services, website}) => {
      const filter = this.filter.toLowerCase()

      return (
        name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || notes.toLowerCase().includes(filter)... // so on and so forth
      )
    })
  }
}
```

But I can't seem to make the boolean (`inactive`) field to work. How can I filter by either inactive false or inactive true?

EDIT:
Ended up getting it to work using this, but is it efficient?
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: filter is looking for boolean return which you are doing using includes which returns boolean and you can include inactive in the return.
Suggestion: you don't have to include `const filter = this.filter.toLowerCase()` in the filter function because its the same value evaluated again, so you can take it out out the `.filter()` function
`const allInactives = data.filter(v => v.inactive);`
`const allActives = data.filter(v => !v.inactive);`

Comment: Thanks I adjusted my code per your recommendation!

Comment: You don't have to add two filters, you can just do this in one filter
`data.filter(v => inactive === this.inactiveVendor && (v.name.includes(...) || v.notes...))`

Answer (score 0):

To filter a list of data:

```js
data.filter(x => x.inactive)
```

```js
var data = [
{
    "user_updated": null,
    "user_created": "128a84b5-275c-4f00-942e-e8ba6d85c60e",
    "date_created": "2021-03-13T23:41:09Z",
    "date_updated": null,
    "website": "www.example.com",
    "payment_information": "IBAN: THEIR1234IBAN567",
    "tax_id": null,
    "vat_id": "1234567890",
    "services": "Produzione video, animazioni",
    "name": "Video Productions Ltd.",
    "address": "Viale Lorenteggio, 20\nMilano 20142",
    "notes": "Competenze di alto livello",
    "id": 1,
    "inactive": false
}
];

console.log(data.filter(x => x.inactive))

console.log(data.filter(x => x.id == 1))
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem relevant to the quesiton.